# cannot change tuning to Eb in Guitar Pro 6

Tags: guitar-pro

I don't seem to be able to change the tuning like I could in older versions of Guitar Pro. When I change the tuning from E to Eb in The Instrument Panel, the track immediately bounces back.

It happens both for an old .gp4 file converted to .gpx and with a new .gpx file I created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you move the tuning of the instrument you need to click on the check mark.
The one I rounded with yellow:

[image: Check Mark belows the Guitar Tuning sketch]

This way the Tab will stay the same with different tuning, and if you click on the left checkmark it will transport your tab to the new tuning.

Comment: thanks that works, if I uncheck the indicated tickbox, the pitch of the instrument changes but the tab stays the same.

This way I can play along to a track without retuning the guitar between E-Eb. Will mark this as the answer.